# 90s anime - A girl fights a demon, whom she eventually marries

Tags: story-identification, anime, demons

I'm looking for a possible 90s anime that my mum spoke about. The things she remembers are brief, but all she can remember is that this girl/woman sets out to protect two people from a demon dude. Then she said she remembered the last part:

> She eventually finds them and battles the demon is whipping her and conveniently her clothes start to rip. He weirdly falls in love with her and then decides to take her to the underworld to marry her while the other two people escape as the castle crumbles

Comment: I think it is Cutie Honey anime, specifically New Cutie Honey. Timeline is ok, but I didn't watch it so I can't post an answer. Also check these as well (Warning, tv tropes link!) : https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WhipItGood

Could also be Sailor Moon I guess, but I doubt it.

Comment: @jo1storm  thx for your response, I appreciate it. Its definitely not sailor moon. As for Cutie Honey I’m not so sure on either I looked it up and it doesn’t seem to be it but I’m not sure I’d feel sorta awkward if I show my mum cuz the nudity but I mean she’s watched Devilman and stuff so it’s not that bad. The synopsis I gave is fairly vague so I wouldn’t expect to get replies. What I do know it’s based around a girl who needs to save a couple from a demon king dude.The ending she was whipped till she was nude then taken as his bride and brought to the underworld 